# calculate cummulative return using loop

Tags: r, for-loop, return

I am currently working on some hedge fund data with monthly returns but I hope to have cummulative return instead. I have tried Return.cummulative function but it doesn't give me my desired results due to NAs in my data set. I have written a loop to get the results but it takes ages to finish looping. I copy my code below and please help me to figure out how I can reduce the looping time. I am a starter in R so my code looks quite stupid. Please feel free to let me know about other alternatives without the loop. My real data set contains 10000+hedge funds and 200+ monthly returns. As you can expect, my code will take hours to finish the calculation. I do believe there are alternatives but at this moment, I have to follow the stupic code I've written.

```
mock<-data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol=2,nrow=4))
rownames(mock)<-as.vector(c("day1","day2","day3","day4"))
colnames(mock)<-as.vector(c("fund1","fund2"))
mock[,1]<-c(NA,-0.08,0.1,0.23)
mock[,2]<-c(NA,-0.08,0.22,NA)
mock
results<-data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol=2,nrow=4))
prev <- 1 
for (j in 1:2){for(i in 1:4) { 
  if (is.na(mock[i,j])) { 
    results[i,j] <- NA 
  } else { 
    results[i,j]<-((1+mock[i,j])*prev) 
  } 
  if(is.na(results[i,j])){prev<-1}else{prev <- results[i,j]} 
} }
results
```

I will appreciate any comment from you. Thanks

Wei

Comment: Slight performance gain, if you put 2 `if else` into one.

Comment: It's not completely obvious to me if your code gives you the expected result. Can you please provide the mathematical formula you are trying to implement?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.Take fund 1 in the mock data set for example, to calculate the cumulative return of fund1 on day3 I need to do (1+day 1 return)*(1+day2 return)*(1+day3 return). As the day1 return is NA, the cummulative return of fund1 on day 3 should equal to (1-0.08)*(1+0.1). It is actually a running product of 1+figures that are not NA.

Comment: It took me quite a while to figure out how you obtain the numbers in `results`.  I think these are the equations for the first column: `1 + -0.08; (1 + 0.10) * 0.92; (1 + 0.23) * 1.012`.  If so, this might help others provide a solution.

Comment: Yes Mark this is how I calculate the results I need. Applologise for the confusing examples.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this over each column?

```
library(data.table)
mock <- data.table(mock)

# initiate mockreturns dataset
mockreturns <- copy(mock)
# overwrite NAs with 0s to allo cumprod to work
mockreturns[is.na(mockreturns)] <- 0
# names of return cols in new dataset
setnames(mockreturns,paste0(colnames(mock),"returns"))
#calculate cumulative interest
mockreturns <- mockreturns[,
      lapply(
        .SD, 
        function(x) 
          cumprod(
            x+1
            )
        )
    ]
#replace the NA returns with NAs
mockreturns[is.na(mock)] <- NA
```

Output -

```
> mockreturns
   fund1returns fund2returns
1:           NA           NA
2:      0.92000       0.9200
3:      1.01200       1.1224
4:      1.24476           NA
```

Thanks Mark, for pointing out that I msised the NA part

Comment: Thanks, @MarkMiller. I'm trying to probe what exactly the OP's eventual requirement is.

Comment: Thanks Codoremifa, this is exactly what I want! I will test to run the code on my real data and see how much time it can help to save. Thanks again!